# Putting Custom View Inside a Custom ScrollView

Tags: java, android, view, scrollview

I am creating an android app with a customized view and a customized `ScrollView`. I am attempting to put the custom view inside of the scroll view. It does not appear to work, as I am just receiving a blank screen.

**Dashboard.java**

```
package com.commentblock.fandoms;

import com.commentblock.fandom.R;
import com.commentblock.fandom.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Dashboard extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Set the content view to the dashbaord
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.setContentView(new StatusViewScroll(this));

    }
}
```

**StatusViewScroll.java**

```
package com.commentblock.fandoms;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class StatusViewScroll extends RelativeLayout {
    public StatusViewScroll(Context c) {
        super(c);
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(c);
        StatusView statusView = new StatusView(c);
        scrollView.addView(statusView);
        addView(scrollView);
    }
}
```

**`StatusView.java`** works just fine without the `ScrollView`, but when I add it to the `ScrollView`, it just breaks. No errors, just a black screen.

Comment: have you tried adding any layout params for the statusView?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); scrollView.addView(statusView, mLayoutParams);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my issue on my own. The problem lies at StatusView.java, where I needed to override the onMeasure event.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    setMeasuredDimension(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
}
```